# Unable to sync up answers the questions on an Android Multiplication app

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with my simple android app. When I launch it, the questions seems to be a step ahead of the answers I enter as input. For example If the question was to be 3x3 = ?, It will only accept the correct answer for the next question. So any answer I give in the current question will always be wrong. I tested this by continuously entering the same same answer. 
Any pointers would be much appreciated. I hope this make sense!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int value3;
    int answer;
    EditText answer_field;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageView leftNumber = findViewById(R.id.left_number);

        final ImageView rightNumber = findViewById(R.id.right_number);

        Button myButton = findViewById(R.id.answer_button);

        final int[] numberArray = new int[]{
                R.drawable.number_0,
                R.drawable.number1,
                R.drawable.number2,
                R.drawable.number3,
                R.drawable.number4,
                R.drawable.number5,
                R.drawable.number6,
                R.drawable.number7,
                R.drawable.number8,
                R.drawable.number9,
        };
        leftNumber.setImageResource(numberArray[0]);
        rightNumber.setImageResource(numberArray[0]);


        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                // Create a random number generator
                Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();


                int value1 = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(10);




                leftNumber.setImageResource(numberArray[value1]);

                // Create a new random number
                int value2 = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(10);

                // Set the right dice image using an image from the diceArray.
                rightNumber.setImageResource(numberArray[value2]);
                answer_field = findViewById(R.id.answer_field);
                answer = valueOf(answer_field.getText().toString());
                value3 = value1 * value2;
                if(value3 == answer) {

                    showToast("Correct");
                }

            }

        });

    }


    public void showToast(String text){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are generating the values at the onClick of your answer button wich means that the values to multiply will be set (or reset) randomly every time the user hit the answer button; put the logic to generate the values outside the onclick, so when the user clicks on it only the comparison will be made, somewhat like this:

```java
[...]

    leftNumber.setImageResource(numberArray[0]);
    rightNumber.setImageResource(numberArray[0]);

     // Create a random number generator
     Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();

     int value1 = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(10);

     leftNumber.setImageResource(numberArray[value1]);

     // Create a new random number
     int value2 = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(10);

     // Set the right dice image using an image from the diceArray.
     rightNumber.setImageResource(numberArray[value2]);
     answer_field = findViewById(R.id.answer_field);

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              answer = valueOf(answer_field.getText().toString());
                value3 = value1 * value2;
                if(value3 == answer) {
                    showToast("Correct");
                }
            }
        });

[...]
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm still very inexperienced at this, and sometimes it's the simple things that stump me!

Comment: @CraigCorstorphine I see, we're here to help each other. If the answer helped you please mark it as "accepted" so others can find it more easily